# How to show specific value in a column - sql (redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a situation where I want to show a value that corresponds to one field in a table but in all rows. What is better is to show you an example in a screenshot:

[image: screen shot]

What I want is to have the value of 3807 in every row? How can I do that?

THank you in advance.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images or links to images.

Comment: Do you want to modify your table so all the rows will have same value in specific column or you just want a query which makes it look like all rows have same value in this column without modifying actual data?

Comment: Hi, Yes I wanted all rows to show that 3807 value, I have succeeded with listagg(distinct bt_max_speed_coverage,'') function and i now it's not optimal but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MAX` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    site_id,
    bt_max_speed,
    MAX(bt_max_speed_on_site_coverage) OVER (PARTITION BY site_id) bt_max_speed_on_site_coverage
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY site_id;
```

Comment: Hi, I don't need max value here, i have succeeded with listagg(distinct bt_max_speed_coverage, '') and I am aware it is not the best possible solution but for now is actually what I needed here

Comment: My answer literally matches your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to update one column so it has same value for all rows you can just use `UPDATE` without any conditions

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET <column_name> = <value>
```

In your case it would look like this, but with  replaced with actual name of your table

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET bt_max_speed_on_site_coverage = 3807
```